# Passing data from Qdialog to main window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to pass data from a `Qdialog` (Login dialog) to my `mainWindow` after a successful login and was wondering if it is possible to use Signals and slots to achieve this. Here is my Main.cpp file so far in which I connect my Login Dialog to main window:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Login l;
    l.createConnection();
    MainWindow w;
    l.show();
    QObject::connect(&l, SIGNAL(accept()), &w, SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(Logout()), &l, SLOT(show()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

The signal accept emits from the Dialog after the user inserts correct username/password and I would like afterwards to pass the information relative to this user to my main window.

The user class I'm trying to pass:

```
class User
    {
    QString ID;
    QString username;
    QString password;
    QString name;
    QString Status;

    public:
        User();
        User(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString);
        ~User();
};
```

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Whats is the information relative?

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand what u mean , if u are asking about the type of the information i want to pass it's a User class containing the username/password etc ..

Comment: Show User Class

Comment: Maybe you could add a parameter to the `accept` signal with the data. Something like `signals: void accept(Data data){...}` in the `Login` class and `QObject::connect(&l, &Loging::accept, [&](Data data){w.setData(data); w.show();});` when connecting the login window and the main window.

Comment: Complementing @DonaldDuck help you must register Data so that it can be used as an argument to the signal: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (Data);`

Comment: edited the post with the user class

Comment: @DonaldDuck that approach seems suitable

Comment: @New_ToQT If you want to use User as a signal parameter then register it: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(User);

Comment: @eyllanesc can u edit my code with the correct way to do this and post it as an answer ?

Comment: @New_ToQT see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new type to be used in the signals you must register it using the macro: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`

**user.h**

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <QString>
#include <QMetaType>

class User
{
    [...]
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(User)

#endif // USER_H
```

Then it is used as parameter of the accept signal in your case:

**login.h**

```
signals:
    void accept(const User & user);
```

Then you issue it when necessary:

```
User user("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
emit accept(user);
```

To make it simple you can connect using a lambda function, but for this we create a method that you get to use in MainWindow:

**mainwindow.h**

```
public:
    void setUser(const User &user);

private:
    User mUser;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::setUser(const User& user)
{
    mUser = user;
    qDebug()<<mUser.toString();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Login l;
    l.createConnection();
    MainWindow w;
    l.show();
    QObject::connect(&l, &Login::accept, [&w](const User user){
        w.setUser(user);
        w.show();
    });
    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::Logout, &l, &Login::show);
    return a.exec();
}
```

You can find a complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47621727).

Comment: thanks a lot man you are a life saver this worked for me !! @eyllanesc